# C# Ковариантность и контрвариантность обобщенных интерфейсов

Tags: c#, интерфейс

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Generics
{

abstract class Animals { }
class Tigers : Animals { }

interface Igetting<out T>
{
  //  void Add(T element);
     
    T this[int index1]
    { get; }
}
class MyList<T>:Igetting<T>
{
    //поля
    private int elements=0;
    private T[] array;

    
    public int Elements
    {
        get { return elements; }
    }

    public MyList(params T[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
        elements = array.Length;
    }
    //реализуемые методы
    public void Add(T element)
    {
        T[] new_array = new T[elements+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            new_array[i] = array[i];
        }
        new_array[new_array.Length - 1] = element;
        array = new_array;
        elements++;
        
    }
    
    public T this[int index1]
    {
        get 
        {
            return array[index1];
        }
    }
    
}




class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        MyList<Tigers> mys = new MyList<Tigers>(new Tigers(), new Tigers(), new Tigers());
      
        Igetting<Animals> obj = mys;
      
        for (int i = 0; i < mys.Elements; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj[i].GetType().ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

хочу добавить метод Add(T element) в обобщенном интерфейсе но не разрешает Почему? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы определили `T` как `out T`. Это значит, что следующий код будет работать:

```
Igetting<Animals> list = new MyList<Tigers>(...);
Animals x = list[0];
```

Такое работает, т. к. `list[0]` имеет реальный тип `Tigers`, а значит, его можно присвоить ссылке на тип `Animals`.

Теперь представьте себе, что компилятор разрешил бы вам добавить **в интерфейс** `void Add(T element)`. Тогда вы смогли бы написать так:

```
Igetting<Animals> list = new MyList<Tigers>(...);
list.Add(new Lions()); // это должно откомпилироваться, ведь Lions - подкласс Animals
```

Катастрофа! Вам в метод `Add` класса `MyList<Tigers>` попал элемент типа `Lions`, а не `Tigers`! Вот чтобы такие катастрофы были невозможны, вам компилятор и запрещает добавление «входящего» параметра с `out`-типом.

Простое правило: `out`-типы можно использовать только для «исходящих» параметров, то есть для возвращаемых значений.

---

Что делать?

- Вы можете добавить метод только в класс, но не в интерфейс.
- Или вы можете завести отдельный интерфейс `IAdding<in T>`, в который добавить нужный метод. И пусть класс реализует оба интерфейса одновременно.
- Ну или вы можете просто убрать `out` из исходного интерфейса.